# Getting much time for latitude and longitude in xamarin from

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin Form PCL application, I want to get the current Latitude and longitude. I am using `Plugin.Geolocator;` sometimes its take very long to get the latitude and longitude of the device. My app has full permission to use device location. Below is my code can you please tell me what is am doing wrong or what i need to make changes in the code to get latitude and longitude faster.

```
            string Latitude = "", Longitude = "";
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            if (locator.IsGeolocationAvailable && locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
            {
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
                Latitude = Convert.ToString(position.Latitude);
                Longitude = Convert.ToString(position.Longitude);
            }
```

Comment: Maybe your device hasn't got a GPS lock yet, and still needs to establish that before it can give you the long and lat?

Comment: @Maarten ok but why this happens only sometimes.  What is the other option if this is taking more than 2 second i can skip this

Comment: You can always specify the milliseconds 
    `Position position = await _locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 1000);`

Comment: @Greggz does not have parameter timeoutMilliseconds

Comment: @A.Goutam How so ? I used it in a project not so long ago

Comment: @A.Goutam that depends on the device, because the device and its OS/firmware because those handle the GPS functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather check before if there is a cached position and if not get a new one.

```
try {
      var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
      locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;

      //Check if we have a cached position
      var loc = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
      if (loc != null) {
          CurrentPosition = new Position(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);
          return;
    }

      if (!locator.IsGeolocationAvailable || !locator.IsGeolocationEnabled) {
          await DisplayAlert ("Location not available", "Ok");
          return;
    }

      //and if not we get a new one
      var def = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null, true);
      CurrentPosition = new Position(def.Latitude, def.Longitude);
   }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("GetCurrentLocation error: " + e);
   }
```